# IF conditional in EJS with Script tag doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I've some problem in here. I put `script` tag inside IF Conditional. Nah, `script` tag is running when condition is TRUE or FALSE.

For example

```js
<% if (info) { %>
    <p><%=info%></p>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Hi")
            </script>
    <% } %>
```

Result :

IF = TRUE

```js
alert("Hello world")
```

```html
<p>Hello world</p>
```

IF = FALSE

```
alert("Hello world")
```

*Paragraph attributes* is rendering when IF conditional is TRUE. But `script` tag is running when IF Conditional is TRUE or FALSE, what i want the `script` tag running like HTML attributes.

Why this is happened? Thanks

Comment: This might be type related; in javascript, `!!'FALSE' === true`

Comment: So what i've to do with my code? Is it impossible to using script tag inside if conditional in EJS? @PaulS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i answer my own questions. This is solved by added `<% if (info.length > 0) { %>`

Since my route file like this

```js
function isAuth(req, res, next){
    var token = req.session.token;
    if(token){
        jwt.verify(token, 'jwtsecret', function(err, decoded){
            if(err){
                req.flash('info', err)
                res.info = req.flash()
                res.redirect('/login')
                return;
            }
            req.decoded = decoded;
            req.session.username = decoded.username
            next();
        })
    }
    else{
        req.flash('info', "Please login first")
        res.redirect('/login')
    }
};

Router.get('/login', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.flash)
    res.render('../views/login', {info : req.flash('info')})
})
```

```html
<% if (info.length > 0) { %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Hello world")
  </script>
  <% } %>
```

Comment: This is a good example of sharing. Don't hesitate to answer our own questions whenever we have a solution.